# c# Copying jagged arrays to strings

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

My function is supposed to split a string by "&" ";" and "," and return a triple jagged array and vice versa. (From data like: 1,2,3;4,5,6&1,2,3;4,5,6)

I've been struggling hard to make it work, now for some reason I'm getting a system.argumentnullexception on

```
Array.Copy(playerOneEnts, allEnts[0], playerOneEnts.Length);
Array.Copy(playerTwoEnts, allEnts[1], playerTwoEnts.Length);
```

Full code:

```
public string convertToString(string[][][] allEnts)
{
    string Player = string.Empty;
    string[][] playerOneEnts = new string[maxEnts][];
    string[][] playerTwoEnts = new string[maxEnts][];

    Array.Copy(allEnts[0], playerOneEnts, allEnts[0].Length);
    Array.Copy(allEnts[1], playerTwoEnts, allEnts[1].Length);

    for (int j = 0; j < playerOneEnts.Length; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerOneEnts[j].Length; i++)
        {
            Player += playerOneEnts[j][i] + ",";
        }

        Player = Player.TrimEnd(',');
        Player += ";";
    }

    Player = Player.TrimEnd(';');
    Player += "&";

    for (int j = 0; j < playerTwoEnts.Length; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerTwoEnts[j].Length; i++)
        {
            Player += playerTwoEnts[j][i] + ",";
        }

        Player = Player.TrimEnd(',');
        Player += ";";
    }

    Player = Player.TrimEnd(';');
    return Player;
}

public string[][][] convertToArray(string ents)
{
    string[] p = new string[2];
    string[][] playerOneEnts = new string[maxEnts][];
    string[][] playerTwoEnts = new string[maxEnts][];
    string[][][] allEnts = new string[2][][];

    p = ents.Split('&');

    try
    {
        playerOneEnts = p[0].Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(chunk => chunk.Split(',')).ToArray();
        playerTwoEnts = p[1].Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(chunk => chunk.Split(',')).ToArray();

        MessageBox.Show(playerOneEnts.Length.ToString());

        Array.Copy(playerOneEnts, allEnts[0], playerOneEnts.Length);
        Array.Copy(playerTwoEnts, allEnts[1], playerTwoEnts.Length);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("unable to convert string", "Fatal Error");
    }

    return allEnts;
}
```

The code looks like a disaster to me, if anyone knows a nicer way to convert this to a string I'd be happy for any ideas. Getting rid of my Error would help me enough already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is example using Linq (requires .Net 4.0):

```
var source = "1,2,3;4,5,6&1,2,3;4,5,6";

string[][][] decoded = source.Split('&').Select(x => x.Split(';').Select(y => y.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray()).ToArray();

string reencoded = String.Join("&", decoded.Select(x => String.Join(";", x.Select(y => String.Join(",", y)))));
```

Alternatively IEnumarable generics can be used to avoid conversion to arrays.

**Warning:** This code doesn't validates input e.g. array lengths.

**Edit:** Re-encoder for .NET 3.5:

```
var reencoded = String.Join("&", decoded.Select(x => String.Join(";", x.Select(y => String.Join(",", y)).ToArray())).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using nested for-loops like this:

```
string p = "1,2,3;4,5,6&1,5,3;4,5,9";
List<List<List<string>>> result = new List<List<List<string>>>();
foreach (var a in p.Split('&'))
{
    List<List<string>> level2 = new List<List<string>>();
    foreach (var b in a.Split(';'))
    {
        level2.Add(new List<string>(b.Split(',')));
    }
    result.Add(level2);
}
var x = result[0][1][2]; // This will result in '6'.
```

The encoding is similar:

```
string encoded;
List<string> dec1 = new List<string>();
foreach (var a in result)
{
    string e = "";
    List<string> z = new List<string>();
    foreach (var b in a)
    {
        z.Add(String.Join(",", b));
    }
    e = String.Join(";", z);
    dec1.Add(e);
}
encoded = String.Join("&", dec1);
```